# Visual Studio prevent indentation of scope braces content

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, indentation

I'm working on a project which uses a lot of "scope braces".

```
void func()
{
    // regular code

    {
        // code in "scope braces"
    }

    // regular code

}
```

Visual Studio by default indents their content, and that makes the code hard to read. 
I'm looking for a way to tell Visual Studio not to indent them. Is this possible?

Comment: [Options, Text Editor, C/C++, Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6hx0kx.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Seems like we have a misunderstanding. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Try the artistic style plugin!

Comment: How on earth is this a relevant, on-topic, programming related question? This is just about a trivial configuration detail for a tool that could easily be solved with a 5sec google search. Finding [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnstudents/2014/02/10/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-formatting-your-code/) took aproximately that time.  Show a little effort, please.

Comment: By the way; I'm currious why you find that indentation (which helps show the structure of the code) *hurts* readability..? That's not something I hear often.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If I didn't search for it, I wouldn't post a question here. If you're so smart, then show me where exactly it is.

Comment: How are we to know that you've tried to research it? You didn't tell us you did, nor what you tried to search for, nor what results you got, nor why those results were not useful, etc etc. Btw, may I recommend [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) - which can in fact be used with Visual Studio : https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/11/05/format-c-code-intelligently-in-visual-studio-with-clang-format/

Comment: @JesperJuhl The link you provided gives me a 404.

Comment: Try again, I fumbled the link the first time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: That extension offers consistent formatting. The OP is apparently looking for **inconsistent** formatting, i.e. `regular code` should get indented, but `code in "scope braces"` should not. I doubt there is tool support for this.